# jQuery append script not fully working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I am making an ajax request to a file and as part of the returned html, there are a few scripts. I am appending the results to a div in my file.The problem is that the code I am inserting has `bind` tags and they apparently don't work. I have tried replacing my bind functions with a quick console message and I see that it is inserting the script. How do I get a click event to work while appending the script, is this even possible? Thanks so much!

---

PS.  I know `.append()` doesn't add the script to the DOM and that I can't view it while browsing the code.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't put the scripts on the page, and exclude or parse them out of the file?

Comment: a simple test shows that bind itself should be executed. Can you include how you're binding, and to what?

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to bind before the element has been added to the DOM? Maybe try `live()` instead?

Comment: @CrisCarew I am binding to the element like this `$('.button').bind("click", function() { //Do stuff here });`

Comment: @AndrewR That made no difference and it still doesn't work. Tried sending a message to the console on bind click/live click but it doesn't do it. I also can't view any console errors but that is to be expected if it isn't added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made a quick fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/xqnWF/4/

And, as you can see if you click "Trigger" and then "Button", it works as intended. Could you shed some more light on the sequence of events or the dom model at the time of binding?

Comment: Here is the sequence of events on my site: 1) User enters text in input -> 2) jQuery sends ajax request to php -> 3) PHP performs an action -> 4) PHP echo's some html with embedded scripts -> 5) jQuery appends the returned html to a div -> 6) Embedded scripts run on user click. This is annoying me because I did this same thing on another place of my site and it works fine, I copied the jquery code and the php does the something just echo's different content.

Comment: And on this one page, the embedded scripts don't bind? Is there something particular about the html, or the order of the html/scripts? Maybe the scripts are trying to bind to something that's sent after the `<script>` tag, and so doesn't exist "yet" at time of evaluation?

Comment: I have checked and I have put them at the absolute bottom of the page, they still don't work. I made sure they were in the the `$(document).ready(function(){ });`, nothing. But I know they are echoing because the console.log function will output something as long as it isn't in a bind function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the eval(); function on the data once appended